# ILOG Cplex out of scope

Tags: cplex, assignment-problem

```
 int nbPilots = 50;
 int nbLocations = 7;
 int nbDays = 30;

 range pilots = 1..nbPilots;
 range days = 1..nbDays; 
 range locations = 1..nbLocations;



 /*decision variable*/
 dvar boolean assign [pilots][days][locations] ;
 dvar boolean rest [pilots][days][locations];

 /*objective*/
 minimize sum(i in pilots, j in days, l in locations)assign[i][j][l];

 /*constraints*/
 subject to{


   //Kısıt-2: Her pilotun art arda gelen 6 gün içerisinde asgari 1 gün boş bırakılması kısıtı
   //forall(i in pilots, j in days, l in locations)(rest[i][j][l]+rest[i][j+1][l]+rest[i][j+2][l]+rest[i][j+3][l]+rest[i][j+4][l]+rest[i][j+5][l]+rest[i][j+6][l]>=1);

   forall(i in pilots, j in days, l in locations)(assign[i][j][l]+assign[i][j+1][l]+assign[i][j+2][l]+assign[i][j+3][l]+assign[i][j+4][l]+assign[i][j+5][l]+assign[i][j+6][l]+rest[i][j+7][l]+rest[i][j+8][l] == 9);
   }
```

**how can i handle that [j+8] is also in days <=30**

Answer (score 2):

```
      int nbPilots = 50; 
int nbLocations = 7; 
int nbDays = 30;

range pilots = 1..nbPilots; range days = 1..nbDays; range locations = 1..nbLocations;

//decision variable/ 

dvar boolean assign [pilots][days][locations] ; dvar boolean rest [pilots][days][locations];

//objective/ 

minimize sum(i in pilots, j in days, l in locations)assign[i][j][l];

//constraints/
 subject to{


forall(i in pilots, j in days, l in locations:(j+8) in days)
  (assign[i][j][l]+assign[i][j+1][l]+assign[i][j+2][l]+assign[i][j+3][l]+
  assign[i][j+4][l]+assign[i][j+5][l]+assign[i][j+6][l]+rest[i][j+7][l]+rest[i][j+8][l] == 9);



}
```

works better

Comment: no value for assign and rest..

Comment: execute
{
  writeln(assign);
}

Comment: nothing changed, no value for assign and rest